# Different behavior of click and enter

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

When clicking on submit button, ajax works and php page called (no refresh) , but when pressing enter it refreshs page and script not work, and only a `?txtname=(INPUTED TEXT)` appears at the end of page URL.

ajax code:

```
var time_variable;
var root2 = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/testing.php';

function getXMLObject()  //XML OBJECT
{
   var xmlHttp = false;
   try {
     xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")  // For Old Microsoft Browsers
   }
   catch (e) {
     try {
       xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")  // For Microsoft IE 6.0+
     }
     catch (e2) {
       xmlHttp = false   // No Browser accepts the XMLHTTP Object then false
     }
   }var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
   if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
     xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        //For Mozilla, Opera Browsers
   }
   return xmlHttp;  // Mandatory Statement returning the ajax object created
}

var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();   //xmlhttp holds the ajax object

function ajaxFunction() {
  var getdate = new Date();  //Used to prevent caching during ajax call
  if(xmlhttp) {
    var txtname = document.getElementById("txtname");
    xmlhttp.open("POST",root2,true); //calling testing.php using POST method
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send("txtname=" + txtname.value); //Posting txtname to PHP File
  }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
     if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; //Update the HTML Form element
     }
     else {
        alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
     }
   }
}
```

html part:

```
<body>
<form name="myForm">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Enter Name</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" value="<?php echo $f ?>" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="ajaxFunction();" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
<div id="message" name="message"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please, stop attaching events via tag attributes in HTML.

Comment: It looks like the form is getting submitted on Enter press. This should not have happened as your input type is button and not submit. try putting a return false onSubmit method of the form.

Comment: Are you aware that `xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")  // For Old Microsoft Browsers` refers to IE5 and IE5.5 .. emm .. You sure that this was your original intention, or just a bad case of copy-paste ?

Comment: ajax part is not mine and copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `onsumbit` attribute to your form:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="ajaxFunction(); return false;">
```

`return false;` is to prevent page to refresh (i.e. real submiting instead of ajax).

Answer (score 2):

Apply handler to submit of a form, not a button click

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="ajaxFunction();">
```

This way your function will work in any case, be form submitted via enter or button click.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
<form name="myForm">
```

with

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="ajaxFunction();return false;">
```

because the form will submit itself with GET method on the page itself with ENTER unless you define what to do on ENTER keypress.